# What does the group of the geometric images of z, such that $z+\overline{z}+|z^2|=0$ define?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> What does the group of the geometric images of z, such that
>   $z+\overline{z}+|z^2|=0$ define?
>
> A) A circumference of center (0,-1) and radius 1.
>
> B) Two lines, of equations $y=x+2$ and $y=x$.
>
> C)A circumference of center (1,0) and radius 1.
>
> D)A circumference of center (-1,0) and radius 1.

I tried to simplify the expression:

$$z+\overline{z}+|z^2|=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
x+yi+x-yi+|(x+yi)^2|=0\Leftrightarrow \\
2x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}=-2x \Leftrightarrow \\
(x^2+y^2)^2+(2xy)^2=4x^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
x^4 - 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4+4x^2y^2 = 4x^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2 = 4x^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
???$$

How do I continue from here?

I have also been thinking that if the sum of those three numbers is zero then they could be the vertices of a triangle. I rewrote the expression:

$$\rho \cdot cis(\theta)+\rho cis(-\theta)+|\rho^2 \cdot cis(2\theta)|=0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho \cdot cis(\theta)+\rho cis(-\theta)+\rho^2 =0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho(cis(\theta)+cis(-\theta)+\rho) = 0  \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho = 0 \lor cis(\theta)+cis(-\theta)+\rho = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
cis(\theta)+cis(-\theta) = -\rho \Leftrightarrow \\
\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i+\cos(-\theta)+\sin(-\theta)i = -\rho \Leftrightarrow \\
\cos(\theta)+\cos(\theta) = -\rho  \Leftrightarrow \\
2\cos(\theta) = -\rho \Leftrightarrow \\
\rho = -2\cos(\theta)$$

This means that $\rho$ will be between 0 and 2. If $|z^2|=\rho^2 = \rho^2 cis(0)$, then one of the vertices is $4$.

But what do I do next? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That solution is very laboured: $|z^2|=x^2+y^2$ so the curve's equation is
$$x^2+y^2+2x=0$$
or
$$(x+1)^2+y^2=1.$$
I'm sure you can identify the curve now.

Answer (score 1):

Put $z=\rho (\cos (t)+i \sin (t))$.
We have

$$z+\overline {z}=2\rho \cos (t) $$
$$|z^2|=|z|^2=\rho^2$$

thus $$\rho=-2\cos (t) $$
and

$$z=-2\cos^2 (t)-2i\cos (t)\sin (t) $$

or
$$x_z=-1-\cos (2t) $$
$$y_z=-\sin (2t) $$
thus

$$(x_z+1)^2+y_z^2=1$$

it is a circle with radius $1$ and center $(-1,0) $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  using $|z^2|=|z|^2= z \bar z\,$:

$$
0 = z+\bar{z}+|z^2| = z + \bar z + z \bar z \color{red}{+1-1}=(z+1)(\bar z + 1) -1 = |z+1|^2 - 1 \iff |z+1|^2 = 1
$$